# How to limit wildcard length for grep

Tags: bash, grep

For example when I'm doing `grep -rhai 'part1.*part2'` I'd like `.*` to be no more than ***n*** characters long. Unfortunately I can't use `.` because while I might know that ***n*** is less than 5, I have no idea what length is it exactly. Is there any way to specify that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Extended regex](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) you can do it like:

```
grep -rhaiE 'part1.{1,5}part2'
```

where the `{1,5}` after the `.` says to match anywhere from 1 to 5 times.

Comment: Thanks! I do use -E when I incorporate variable parts like this. Will it also work for {0,n}?

Comment: @tyrande Yes, you can just say `{,n}` in that case.

Comment: @Barmar, `{,n}` is not specified by POSIX. It's a GNU extension (and specified as so in GNU `grep`'s man page).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf It's also in PCRE, I thought it was pretty standard across all RE engines.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep 'part1.\{0,5\}part2'
```

See point 5 of [*Matching Multiple Characters* in the POSIX reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_06).